# Secure content and Accordion Scripts

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-accordion

Ok, I'm in the middle of an aspstorefront redesign and I am running into a couple problems with a sidebar accordion and https here: https://www.davidscottco.com/default.aspx?skinid=3

In IE9 I get an "Only secure content is displayed" message and the accordion does not render.  In Chrome I don't get any message but the accordion does not render.

Here's my code:

```
<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false"       Inherits="AspDotNetStorefront.TemplateBase" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ComponentArt" Namespace="ComponentArt.Web.UI" Assembly="ComponentArt.Web.UI" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>(!METATITLE!)</title>
(!CURRENCY_LOCALE_ROBOTS_TAG!)
<meta name="description" content="(!METADESCRIPTION!)">
<meta name="keywords" content="(!METAKEYWORDS!)">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantora+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/style.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/formValidate.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var icons = {
        header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
        activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        icons: icons
    });
    $( "#toggle" ).button().click(function() {
        if ( $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" ) ) {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", null );
        } else {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", icons );
        }
    });
});
</script>


<script runat="server">

protected void PageMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

//the page being viewed
string mItem = Page.Request.FilePath.Substring(Page.Request.FilePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).ToLower();
string mItem2 = Page.Request.RawUrl.ToString().Substring(Page.Request.RawUrl.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).ToLower();

//If home page, Home selected
if (mItem == "default.aspx") {
    PageMenu.Items[0].LookId = "SelectedTopItemLook";

//If a category, Category selected
//} else if ((mItem == "showcategory.aspx") || (mItem == "showproduct.aspx")) {
//  PageMenu.Items[1].LookId = "SelectedTopItemLook";

//If a department, Department selected
} else if ((mItem == "showsection.aspx") || (mItem == "showproduct.aspx")) {
    PageMenu.Items[1].LookId = "SelectedTopItemLook";

//if one of the customer services, Customer Service selected
} else if (mItem2 == "t-about.aspx") {
    PageMenu.Items[2].LookId = "SelectedTopItemLook";
}

// product: (mItem == "showproduct.aspx")
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-3294475-1");
pageTracker._initData();
pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>


(!BUYSAFEJSURL!)
</head>
<body>
<div class="body_bg2"> (!XmlPackage Name="skin.adminalert.xml.config"!)
(!PAGEINFO!)
<div id="hbg">
<div id="hwrap">
<div id="login"> <span id="loginText"><a href="(!SIGNINOUT_LINK!)" class="btn_util">(!SIGNINOUT_TEXT!)</a></span> <span id="userName">(!USERNAME!)</span> <!-- Utility Links -->

            </div>
            <div class="utility">
                <a href="wishlist.aspx"><span class="btn_util_left">Your Wishlist</span></a><span class="pipe">|</span>
                <a href="shoppingcart.aspx"><span class="btn_util_left">Shopping Cart ((!NUM_CART_ITEMS!))</span></a><span class="pipe">|</span>
                <a href="t-contact.aspx"><span class="btn_util_left">Contact Us</span></a><span class="pipe">|</span>
                <a href="account.aspx"><span class="btn_util_left">Your Account</span></a><span class="pipe">|</span>
                <a href="account.aspx">Track Your Order</a><span class="pipe">|</span>
                <a href="t-returns.aspx">Returns</a><span class="pipe">|</span>
                <a href="t-shipping.aspx">Shipping Policy</a>
            </div>
            <!-- END Utility Links -->

        <div id="header">

            <a id="logo" href="default.aspx" title="YourCompany.com"><b>(!SITENAME!)</b></a>
            <div class="logo-tagline">Distributor of Medical Supplies<br>
                Manufacturer of Soft Format Pressure Management Products</div>
        </div>

        <div id="contact">
        <div id="soc"><a href="#"><img src="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/images/fb.png"></a><a href="#"><img src="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/images/tw.png"></a><a href="#"><img src="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/images/pin.png"></a><a href="#"><img src="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/images/yt.png"></a></div>
        <span class="number"><a href="tel:800-804-0333">1.800.804.0333</a></span>

        </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="horizNav">
            <!-- TOP MENU -->
            <ComponentArt:Menu id="PageMenu" OnLoad="PageMenu_Load"
                ClientScriptLocation="skins/componentart_webui_client/"
              ImagesBaseUrl="skins/skin_1/images/"
              ScrollingEnabled="true"
              ScrollUpLookId="ScrollUpItemLook"
              ScrollDownLookId="ScrollDownItemLook"
              Orientation="horizontal"
              CssClass="TopMenuGroup"
              DefaultGroupCssClass="MenuGroup"
              DefaultItemLookID="DefaultItemLook"

                    DefaultSelectedItemLookId="SelectedTopItemLook"
                    DefaultChildSelectedItemLookId="SelectedTopItemLook"

              DefaultGroupItemSpacing="1"
              ExpandDelay="0"
              ExpandDuration="0"
              ExpandSlide="None"
              ExpandTransition="None"
              CascadeCollapse="false"
              CollapseDelay="0"
              CollapseSlide="None"
              CollapseTransition="None"
              EnableViewState="false"
              runat="server">
                <ItemLooks>
                      <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookId="DefaultItemLook" HoverCssClass="MenuItemHover" LabelPaddingTop="2px" ActiveCssClass="MenuItemDown" LabelPaddingRight="15px" LabelPaddingBottom="2px" ExpandedCssClass="MenuItemDown" LabelPaddingLeft="5px" CssClass="MenuItem" />

                      <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookId="TopItemLook" CssClass="TopMenuItem" HoverCssClass="TopMenuItemHover" LabelPaddingLeft="4" LabelPaddingRight="4" LabelPaddingTop="2" LabelPaddingBottom="2" />

                      <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookId="SelectedTopItemLook" CssClass="SelectedTopMenuItem" HoverCssClass="" LabelPaddingLeft="4" LabelPaddingRight="4" LabelPaddingTop="2" LabelPaddingBottom="2" />


                      <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookID="ScrollUpItemLook" ImageUrl="scroll_up.gif" ImageWidth="15" ImageHeight="13" CssClass="ScrollItem" HoverCssClass="ScrollItemH" ActiveCssClass="ScrollItemA" />
                      <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookID="ScrollDownItemLook" ImageUrl="scroll_down.gif" ImageWidth="15" ImageHeight="13" CssClass="ScrollItem" HoverCssClass="ScrollItemH" ActiveCssClass="ScrollItemA" />
                      <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookID="BreakItem" ImageUrl="break.gif" ImageHeight="1" ImageWidth="100%" />




                        </ItemLooks>
        </ComponentArt:Menu>
            <!-- END TOP MENU -->
            <div id="search">   
            <form name="topsearchform" method="get" action="search.aspx">
                <fieldset>
                <label>Search:</label>
                <input type="text" size="15" name="SearchTerm" class="searchBox" id="searchBox" autocomplete="off" onFocus="javascript:this.style.background='#ffffff';" onBlur="javascript:this.style.background='#dddddd';" />
                <input type="button" onClick="document.topsearchform.submit()" title="Click Go to Submit" id="Go" class="submit" value="Go" />
                <br />
                </fieldset>
            </form> 
            </div>  
        </div>

    <div class="wrapper_pad">



        <div id="bodyWrapper">
            <!-- <div id="miniCart">You have (!NUM_CART_ITEMS!) item(s) in your <a class="username" href="shoppingcart.aspx">
                (!CARTPROMPT!)</a></div> -->
            <div id="breadcrumb">Now In: (!SECTION_TITLE!)</div>
            <div id="leftWrap">

                <%--<div class="navHeader">Browse (!StringResource Name="AppConfig.ManufacturerPromptPlural"!)</div>

                                <div class="leftNav" id="manufacturers">(!XmlPackage Name="rev.manufacturers"!)</div>--%>
                <div id="accordion">


                            <h3>Industries</h3><%--Browse (!StringResource Name="AppConfig.SectionPromptPlural"!)--%>
                            <div class="submenu">
                            (!XmlPackage Name="rev.industries"!)
                            </div>                              
                            <h3>(!StringResource Name="AppConfig.CategoryPromptPlural"!)</h3>
                            <div class="submenu">
                            <div class="scroll-pane" id="categories">(!XmlPackage Name="rev.categoriesshow2ndlevel"!)</div> 
                            </div>      
                            <h3>Best Sellers</h3>
                            <div class="submenu">
                            (!XmlPackage Name="sidebar.bestsellers.xml.config"!)    
                            </div>
                </div>

                <div id="addess">
                <div class="street"><B>David Scott Company</B><br >59 Fountain Street<br />Framingham , MA 01702</div>
                <div class="phone">800.804.0333<br />508.875.3333</div>
                <div class="email"><a href="mailto:customerservice@davidscottco.com">Customerservice@davidscottco.com</a></div>
                </div>



                <div class="logo2" title="Blue Diamond">
                <div class="logo2-tagline">Blue Diamond&reg; Positioners &amp; Accessories</div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <!-- CONTENTS START -->
                <div class="mani-cats" id="hp-cats">(!XmlPackage Name="rev.industries2"!)</div>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PageContent" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

                <!-- CONTENTS END -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footerWrap">
                <ul class="tame" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                    <li><strong>All Content &copy; 
                            <SCRIPT> //automatically update year.
                                    var year = new Date();
                                    year = year.getYear();
                                    if (year < 1900) year += 1900;
                                    document.write(year);
                            </SCRIPT>  David Scott Company. All Rights Reserved.
                        </strong>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="tameHoriz">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="t-about.aspx">About Us</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>

                    <li><a href="account.aspx">Track Your Order</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="t-returns.aspx">Returns</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="t-privacy.aspx">Privacy Policy</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="t-faq.aspx">FAQ</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="t-contact.aspx">Contact Us</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="sitemap2.aspx">Site Map</a></li>
                </ul>
                <%--<ul class="tameHoriz" style="margin-top:5px;">
                    <li><a href="t-affiliate.aspx">Affiliates</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="giftregistry.aspx">Gift Registry</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="wishlist.aspx">Wishlist</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="t-privacy.aspx">Privacy Policy</a> <span class="pipe">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="t-security.aspx">Security</a></li>
                </ul>--%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- wrapper -->
<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="100%">(!BUYSAFESEAL!)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<noscript>
Powered by <a href="http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com" target="_blank">shopping cart</a>
</noscript>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's the example I'm trying to setup: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#custom-icons

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Matt

Answer (score 3):

Your jquery and jquery UI scriptlinks are referrencing a http location, you need to either host them yourself or find a hosted version that supports https and link to them via https

That is why the insecure content message is being displayed